# Definition of antiderivative - is it okay for $f$ to be non-integrable?

Tags: calculus, integration, definition

I'm trying to figure out if the following definition of antiderivative is correct:

> Let $f$ be a function defined on an interval. An antiderivative of $f$ is any function $F$ such that $F' = f$. The collection of all antiderivatives is denoted $\displaystyle \int f(x) dx$.

Is it okay to have no conditions on $f$ that ensure it's integrable?

Comment: This is just a definition; a function $F$ satifying the condition is an antiderivative of $f$. Whether such a thing exists or not is a separate issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$F(x)=\begin{cases} x^2\sin (1/x^2) &\text{ if } 0<x\leq 1\\ 0 & \text{ if } x=0\end{cases}$$ You can check that $F$ is differentiable on $[0,1]$. Set $f:=F'.$ Note that $F'$ is not bounded on $[0,1]$, so it is not Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$. Thus, $f$ has an anti-derivative, namely $F$, but it is not Riemann integrable.

Comment: It can be integrable in the definite integral sense. It is integrable in that sense.

Comment: @Jakobian I'm not sure what you mean. Could you re-phrase that?

Comment: If an anti-derivative of $f$ exists, we can always define $\int_a^b f(x) dx = F(b)-F(a)$ for a chosen anti-derivative $F$. This is integration in the definite integral sense. It doesn't always correspond to Riemann integration as shows example. And if we follow that type of integrability, then every function with anti-derivative is integrable.

Comment: $\int_a^b f(x)\, dx$ generally denotes Riemann integration.  The issue with defining $\int_a^b f(x)\, dx = F(b)-F(a)$ in this case is that you need $f$ to be continuous on $[a,b]$.  In this case, $F'$ is not continuous at $0$, so the FTOC doesn't apply.  You can certainly define $\int_{\varepsilon}^{1}F'(x)\,dx$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$, but not on the entire closed interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. I assumed that they meant Riemann integrability, but perhaps, I shouldn’t have.

Comment: @cmk No, I think this was a good assumption. It's just that the person who asked the question might like to know about this.